# Give me clapping

Tags: grammar

1. Give me a clap.
2. Give me clapping.

Why #2 is not used compared to #1, even though you don't want to see just one clap of hands?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that one is used but the other isn't?

Comment: Where have you seen or heard #1 used when asking for multiple claps? Do you mean multiple people each doing one clap, or each person doing multiple claps?

Comment: Just don't say "Give me the clap".

Comment: Thank you, everybody. @Dan Getz, the lather. Then, what is the exact difference between give me a clap, claps, clapping, and some clapping; and why do people use a clap to ask clapping?

Comment: @Catija, why no the clap?

Comment: "The Clap" is another name for an STD called "[Gonorrhea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonnococcal_infection)".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is not enough context and/or details to form a reference point from which to answer the question.

Comment: @DanGetz That's a perfectlynormal way to ask people for a round of applause "give him a clap".

Comment: @pazzo It's a perfectly normal question about English usage. There is no need for Joe Kim to justify his observation of the normal English. His obsertvation is correct as any native speaker knows. His question is why' it like that?

Comment: In American English we don't say *Give him a clap* to mean *give him a round of applause* @Araucaria.

Comment: @pazzo It's very common in the UK ...

Comment: After thinking more, I'm pretty sure I've heard this before in the US. (And I know for certain I've heard people make *puns* about it, which means it must be a real expression.) The question "why" seems ambiguous to me... is this a question about etymology? Or "how do I reconcile this in my head so I remember how to use it?" This isn't Lojban, after all.

Answer (score 2):

*Applause* is what people do when they clap over a duration of time to celebrate something as a group.  So if that's want you want, say *give me applause.*

However, you may want a group of people to clap over a period of time, but not necessarily to celebrate anything.  You could then say *Give me some clapping* or *Everyone, clap for me.*

But really,*give me clapping,* doesn't sound jarring or bad to me as a native AmE speaker.  So you can say this to request some clapping and shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: You lost me after *applause*. I would never say *Give me clapping* or *give me some clapping*. They sound like foreigner speak.

Comment: The usual phrases are "give [someone] a hand", "give [someone] a round of applause", or "give it up for" someone. (Asking for applause for yourself sounds a little strange to begin with).

Comment: I think it would be much more common to say something like "Everybody clap their hands".  "Give me clapping" does sound unusual, at least to this American.